# How to use the "application" object in a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If we are coding a JSP file, we just need to use the embedded "application" object. But how to use it in a Servlet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `application` object in JSP is called the [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object in a servlet. This is available by the inherited [`GenericServlet#getServletContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext--) method. You can call this anywhere in your servlet except of the `init(ServletConfig)` method.

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException { 
         ServletContext ctx = getServletContext(); 
         // ...
    } 

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException { 
         ServletContext ctx = getServletContext(); 
         // ...
    } 

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException { 
         ServletContext ctx = getServletContext(); 
         // ...
    } 

}
```

See also [Different ways to get Servlet Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837285/differents-ways-to-get-servlet-context).

Answer (score 4):

The [application](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro7.html) object references [javax.servlet.ServletContext](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and you should be able to reference that in your servlets.

To reference the ServletContext you will need to do the following:

```
// Get the ServletContext
ServletConfig config = getServletConfig();
ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext();
```

From then on you would use the sc object in the same way you would use the application object in your JSPs.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ServletContext application = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Java web application you often have the `request` object. So you can get the `"application"` object like this:

```
request.getServletContext().getServerInfo()
```