# Different ways to get Servlet Context

Tags: java, servlets

Could anybody explain me what is the difference between this ways of getting the `ServletContext` of an `HttpServlet`?

```
doGet( HttpServletRequest request, ... ){
    getServletConfig( ).getServletContext( );
    request.getSession( ).getServletContext( );
    getServletContext( );
}
```

Is there any difference in performance or in the context itself? If so, which is the best way? Are there any other way of retrieving the context?

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's one more.

```
request.getServletContext();
```

There's technically no difference in performance, only the `request.getSession()` will implicitly create the HTTP session object if not created yet. So if this is not done yet, then grabbing the servlet context via the session may take a few nanoseconds longer if the session isn't created yet.

There's also no difference in the returned context. Those methods are all just for convenience and which method to obtain the context depends on the context ;) you're currently sitting in.

If you're sitting in a method invoked by servlet's [`service()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-) (such as `doGet()`, `doPost()`, etc), then just use the inherited [`getServletContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext--) method. Other ways only unnecessarily add more characters to the source code.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

If you're sitting in servlet's [`init(ServletConfig)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-) method, then the inherited `getServletContext()` isn't available yet as long as you haven't called `super.init(config)`. You'd need to grab it from [`ServletConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html#getServletContext--).

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

But much better is to override [`init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init--) instead. In a decent servlet you usually never need to override `init(ServletConfig)`.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

If you're not sitting in a servlet but in e.g. a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which lacks the inherited `getServletContext()` method and you only have [`ServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext--) at hands, then you could grab it from there.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

Note that this is new since Servlet 3.0. Previously, you'd have to grab it from the session.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

This is however not nice if you worry about unnecessary session creation. Hence the introduction of `ServletRequest#getServletContext()` — although you could also simply extract it from [`FilterConfig`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterConfig.html) (hey, there's yet another way!).

```
private FilterConfig config;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

And then there are [HTTP session listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) where you could listen on a.o. session destroy. There's no other way to obtain the servlet context than via [`HttpSession#getServletContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getServletContext--).

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getSession().getServletContext();
    // ...
}
```

Here you don't need to worry about unnecessary session creation because it's at that point already created for long beforehand. Do note that there's no `ServletRequest` anywhere as there's not necessarily means of an active HTTP request during server side session timeout.

As last, there's also [`ServletContext#getContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext-java.lang.String-) which returns the `ServletContext` of a different web application deployed to same server (this works only if the server is configured to enable cross context access on the target webapp).

```
ServletContext otherContext = context.getContext("/otherContextPath");
```

But this already requires the current `ServletContext` to start with, for which you should by now already know which way to use to obtain it.