# Reading getServletContext() from static method

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way I can read getServletContext() in a normal static java method? i.e. a class which is not a servlet

My web.xml contains:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>paramname</param-name>
    <param-value>test value</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

and static class:

```
public classname
{
    public static boolean methodname() 
    {
        String name=javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext().getInitParameter("paramname");

        // other processing
    }

}
```

I know I cannot access non-static method from a static class but trying to get a workaround.

I can do this is a servlet class. However my JSP page is calling a static method. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access it magically without first grabbing it at the first time where it is made available by the Servlet API's and then make it available as a static variable via a Util class.

For more places from where you can grab `ServletContext` check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837285/different-ways-to-get-servlet-context).

In the servlet

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) {
    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
    ServletConfigUtil.config = config;
}
```

and then you Util class

```
public class ServletConfigUtil {

public static ServletContext sc = null;

public static ServletContext  getServletContext(){
return sc ;
}
```